# HTML5 Local save/load

Tags: html, save, local

Im trying to follow tutorial from this site  " [Link to Tutorial](http://dhmholley.co.uk/incrementals-part-2.html) " to make a idle game.

It shows easy way to make simple local save function, but I can't make it work for some reason. He tells to make a function this and that, but doesn't show how it should look like.

I searched google and saw many different ways, I got some to work but not fully and they weren't simple enough for my lack of knowledge in HTML.
Any help is welcome and appreciated :) thanks in advance.

```
function save(){
    var save = {
    cookies: cookies,
    cursors: cursors
}
localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load(){
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (typeof savegame.cookies !== "undefined") cookies = savegame.cookies;
};
```

```js
var cookies = 0;

function cookieClick(number) {
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

var cursors = 0;

function buyCursor() {
  var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out the cost of this cursor
  if (cookies >= cursorCost) { //checks that the player can afford the cursor
    cursors = cursors + 1; //increases number of cursors
    cookies = cookies - cursorCost; //removes the cookies spent
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors; //updates the number of cursors for the user
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies; //updates the number of cookies for the user
  };
  var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, cursors)); //works out the cost of the next cursor
  document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextCost; //updates the cursor cost for the user
};


function save() {
  var save = {
    cookies: cookies,
    cursors: cursors
  }
  localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load() {
  var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
  if (typeof savegame.cookies !== "undefined") cookies = savegame.cookies;
}


window.setInterval(function() {

  cookieClick(cursors);

}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="cookieClick(1)">Click Me!</button>
  <br />Cookies: <span id="cookies">0</span>
  <br />
  <button onclick="buyCursor()">Buy Cursor</button>
  <br />Cursors: <span id="cursors">0</span>
  <br />Cursor Cost: <span id="cursorCost">10</span>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser may not support localstorage.
You can check broswer's localstorage support using Modernizr.
Read about it here: http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

Also make sure, that you are calling save() method in your code (I don't see it in your code)

Comment: Thanks I got it now :D